# CSS - Overflow scroll and padding right ignored

Tags: css, overflow, margin, padding

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.d1 {
    background-color: lightblue;
    display: flex;
    overflow: scroll;
    padding: 10px;
}
.d2 {
    background-color: yellow;
    margin: 5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="d1">
    <div class="d2">111111111111111111111</div>
    <div class="d2">111111111111111111111</div>
    <div class="d2">111111111111111111111</div>
    <div class="d2">111111111111111111111</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

In this simple example I use both `padding` on the parent `div` and `margin` on the `child` but there is no `padding` or `margin` on the far right of the container... How can I solve this problem? Ty

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the same issue. I have copied your code to my codepan: https://codepen.io/blackcityhenry/pen/ZEEBwLR. I can see the padding & margin is working there.

Comment: not if u resize the window

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.d1 {
    background-color: lightblue;
    display:inline-flex;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 10px;
}
.d2 {
    background-color: yellow;
    margin: 5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="d1">
    <div class="d2">111111111111111111111</div>
    <div class="d2">111111111111111111111</div>
    <div class="d2">111111111111111111111</div>
    <div class="d2">111111111111111111111</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to keep the lightblue padding when the scroll bar appear. You will have to separate the scroll container and the padding container in order to achieve this.

I suggest you change the HTML into this:

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,body{
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper{
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  max-width: 500px;
}
.scroll{
  overflow-x: scroll; /* or auto */
  display: flex;
}
.content{
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="scroll">
    <div class="content">loremipsumloremipsum</div>
    <div class="content">loremipsumloremipsum</div>
    <div class="content">loremipsumloremipsum</div>
    <div class="content">loremipsumloremipsum</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also check out this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/blackcityhenry/pen/ZEEBwLR)